# LinearLayout space distribution with image,text and image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linearlayout with 2 image views and a text view. I want proper space distribution within the layout row. It should be somethink like below

```
______________________________
|IV|                       |IV|
|  | <-- Text View ----->  |  |
_______________________________
```

How can I achieve this? I want all the space assigned to textview after fitting the two images.

Below is my attempt and its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/addTrip"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Enter trip name"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using this as Layout inflater.

```
 ArrayList<TripInfo> trips = inst.getListOfTrips(); //reading from DB


        for (int i =0; i < trips.size(); i++) {
            TripInfo tobj = trips.get(i);
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout lrow = (LinearLayout)vi.inflate(R.layout.triprow, null);
           ((TextView)lrow.getChildAt(1)).setText(tobj.getName());
           placeHolderLinearLayout.addView(lrow);
        }
```

Experts please provide some input. Do I have to set anything in the code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both image views should have: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and no `android:layout_weight` specified.

And the central `TextView` should have `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`.

---

In fact it doesn't matter if you have `1` or any other value specified as weigght. As long as this is the only view that has `layout_weight` it takes up all free space. So you can easily fix you example just by removing `android:layout_weight="0.2"` in last `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But This is not working for me. Its currently coming as wrapped image-text-image<empty space >. Between graphical layout of xml is correctly shown but whil I inflate and add to linearlayout it doesn't.

Comment: You should also specify a parent when inflating: `vi.inflate(R.layout.triprow, parent, false);`

Comment: what would be parent here, placeHolderLinearLayout?? To which this view is getting added. I tried parent as placeHolderLinearLayout again its now working. This seems strange to me probably I am not getting the concept indepth.